# Can I compare Fixed effect regression with IV regression.?

Tags: causality, biostatistics, fixed-effects-model, instrumental-variables

0

How can I analyze the causal effect of variable X on Y using cross-sectional data? I have employed IV regression, but now I want to test the effect of X on Y specifically for individuals belonging to the same village, town, or household. Since I lack variables to control for the village or town characteristics, which are unobserved, would fixed effect regression be appropriate for this comparison? However, I am aware that we cannot establish causality through fixed effect regression alone. Is there any alternative model that can address the endogeneity of variable X and the unobservable characteristics at the village or town level, enabling the identification of the causal effect of X on Y?

I have done IV regression and I have done fixed effect regression. Both these results shows that there is an positive effect of X on Y.